# TypeError: $(...).data(...).text is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

any help on this code? I have the following code:

```
    $('.rnyck').click(function() {

    var nyckcontjs=$(this).data('subject2').text();
    console.log(nyckcontjs);
    $('#nyckcont').html(nyckcontjs);
    var nyckid=$(this).data('nyckcontjs');
    $('#nyckid').val(nyckid);

});
```

In this code the line of var nyckcontjs is not working, it produces an error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).text is not a function
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (personal.js:9)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.js:5237)
at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.4.1.js:5044)
```

The contencts of $(this).data('subject2') is:

```
 Для того чтобы превратить вашу идею в то, что можно "достигать" используйте ментальные карты. Они помогут вам в реализации ваших идей, и позволят вам найти новые идеи для вашей счастливой жизни. Ментальные карты очень легко использовать, это бесплатно и доступно всем. Не ждите, начните их использовать прямо сейчас. Начать можно с сервиса <a href="https://www.mindmeister.com/" target="_blank">Mind Meister</a>.
```

I saw one solution to go with something like that:

```
    $('.rnyck').click(function() {

    var $this=$(this).data('subject2');
    // console.log(nyckcontjs);
    var nyckcontjs=$($this).text();
    $('#nyckcont').html(nyckcontjs);
    var nyckid=$(this).data('nyckcontjs');
    $('#nyckid').val(nyckid);

});
```

Then it goes with new error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Для того чтобы превратить вашу идею в то, что можно "достигать" используйте ментальные карты. Они помогут вам в реализации ваших идей, и позволят вам найти новые идеи для вашей счастливой жизни. Ментальные карты очень легко использовать, это бесплатно и доступно всем. Не ждите, начните их использовать прямо сейчас. Начать можно с сервиса <a href="https://www.mindmeister.com/" target="_blank">Mind Meister</a>.
at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.4.1.js:1560)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery-3.4.1.js:2216)
at Sizzle.select (jquery-3.4.1.js:2643)
at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-3.4.1.js:862)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.4.1.js:2896)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-3.4.1.js:3006)
at jQuery (jquery-3.4.1.js:152)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (personal.js:11)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.js:5237)
at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.4.1.js:5044)
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Note `data()` returns a string or undefined so it wouldnt have a `text()` function. Just use what is returned from `data()` as your argument for `html()`

Comment: I would like to remove HTML characters from the string returned from data.

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML characters"?

Comment: @Undry The second one - you can't do `$($this)` as the content of `$this` contains the Russian(?) characters and you are trying to access that. For just getting the text content, you can try using `$('<div>' + $this + '</div>').text()` or something like that.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman you are GENIUS!!! Thanks :) It worked perfectly. And you explained why :) Thank you for you great idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.data()` returns a `string` or `JSON` as the response. In your case, it should be `string`. All you need to do is lose the `.text()`.

```
var nyckcontjs = $(this).data('subject2');
```

For more information on how `.data()` works, see [`.data()` - jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

---

**Update:** In case, if you need to get only the text content from the `.data()`, what you can do is the following:

- Add the content in an in-memory HTML DOM inside jQuery.
- Apply the `$.text()` on it to get just the text content.

Some sample code for you might be on the order of:

```js
$('.rnyck').click(function() {
  // Get the HTML content from the data attribute.
  var htmlContent = $(this).data('subject2');
  // Now create an in-memory DOM element with the HTML content.
  // And get the text content of the DOM element.
  var nyckcontjs = $('<div>' + htmlContent + '</div>').text();
  // Set your Text Content to wherever you want.
  $('#nyckid').val(nyckcontjs);
});
```

Comment: I would like to remove HTML characters from the string returned from data.

Comment: @Undry The second one - you can't do `$($this)` as the content of `$this` contains the Russian(?) characters and you are trying to access that. For just getting the text content, you can try using `$('<div>' + $this + '</div>').text()` or something like that.

Comment: @Undry I have added comments as well. Hope you find them useful.

Comment: Just to clarify, `.data()` does *not* return "a string or JSON" - it returns a relevant type based on the data.  eg `<div data-id="123">`  `$("div").data("id") === 3 && $("div").data("id") !== "3"`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks.